# Unable to change Wordpress language (Wordpress 4.2.2)

Tags: wp-config, language

So there's a website I'm working on and I need to change language to spanish. I downloaded and uploaded proper .mo and .po files and added the following value to my wp-config file:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'es_ES');
```

I've done this several times before and it's the first time it won't work. Maybe it's an issue with this Wordpress version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the language through your admin panel, go to 'Settings' > 'General', Scroll down and you will find an option for choosing the language.

This is a user friendly option to change the language.

Comment: You are right! How did I missed that? Thanks!

Comment: The constant in wp-config.php is deprecated, you can kill this.