# Unable to change blog language in multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, options, language, configuration

**tl;dr** *No matter what I select in **Site Language**:*

[image]

*After hitting <kbd>Save</kbd> this value is always reset to **English (United States)**. Where or what should I be looking for to resolve this?*

---

I was playing a little bit around [`get_blog_details()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_details/) and I have noticed that I am getting `lang_id` field set to `0` for each and every of my blogs even though I have a multi-language multisite blog network.

I quick investigation revealed that I **truly have** all languages set to *English (United States)*, everywhere, for every blog. A little bit longer query have revealed that no matter what [I set in that field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/187648/17323), I will always have it reset to *English (United States)*.

Some more details:

1. If I select any language that is listed in *Available* group then that language is installed (added to *Installed* group), but again language is reset to *English (United States)*.
2. If I select any language that is listed in *Installed* group then nothing happens (language is set to *English (United States)* after clicking *Save*).

Is there any workaround? I mean *any*:

1. Does anyone recall or recognize such situation and have a cure?
2. Can I force blog language programmatically (from PHP, i.e. from some plugin)?

<sub>This is **not** a duplicate of [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/217880/17323)! I have more than just *English (United States)* language listed. The problem is that I cannot change to any other.</sub>